# App from App store doesn't show up for all users under Notification Center (Local Notifications)

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, app-store, uilocalnotification

Has anyone had any problems with users downloading your app from the app store and the app not showing up in the Notification center (and thus notifications not showing up)? I've tested the app on various devices and haven't been able to recreate the problem that a percentage of my users are having. They email me telling me the app is missing from the Notification center, yet when I download it, it's there. All of my users are using iOS 7 too.

For reference, I've implemented local notifications by following this tutorial
http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/ . Perhaps it's wrong?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue, here is the question I posted yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717805/local-notifications-not-working-for-some-users-ios-8 Have you find a solution or root-caused this issue?

Comment: No luck so far unfortunately. I haven't even been able to successfully recreate the problem. Will probably update the app to iOS8, because in iOS8 you have to register Local notification much like remote ones